# Не могу понять почему не работает echo

Tags: php

Я никак не могу понять, почему echo не работает из if, если в if создать переменную и в конце поставить echo, он выводит пустоту.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_container">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="entersearch" type="text" name="translate">
        <button type="button" id="b" class="b"></button>
        <h1 id="qwerty" class="results">PHP</h1>
    </form>
</div>
 
<script>
$('.b').click( function() {
var input = document.getElementById('entersearch').value;
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'html',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: {text:input},
          success: function(data){
            $('.results').html(data);
          }
        });

    });
    </script>
```

PHP (ajax.php):

```php
<?php
$a  = array('Яблочко','Банан','Смартфон');
$b  = array('Apple','Banana','Smarphone');
$e  = array('æpl','bəˈnɑːnə','ˈsmɑːtfəʊn');//Он поймет транскрипции?
$com = array('Фрукт','Фрукт','Техника');
$usr = $_GET['text'];
function enter($d,$t,$c){
    echo $d.'&'.$t.'&'.$c;
}
if (!empty($usr)){
$tr = strtoupper($usr[0]).substr($usr, 1);
for($i=0;$i<count($b);$i++){
if ($tr==$a[$i]) {enter($b[$i],$e[$i],$com[$i]);break;} 
else if ($tr==$b[$i]) {enter($b[$i],$e[$i],$com[$i]);break;}
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас не выполняется условие `!empty($text)`, переменной `$text` нет.

Comment: И в for, english нету ))

Comment: Все равно выдает пустоту

Comment: Актуализируйте пожалуйста описание кода, чтобы было легче понять что вы делаете. В данный момент у вас много ошибок, кроме предыдущих, например, `$usr[0]` - у вас переменная, а не массив. Также, вы сравниваете числа со строкой apple `$tr==$a[$i]`.
Лучше, опишите общими словами что вы хотите написать, я постараюсь подсказать лучший путь для этого.

Comment: Что-то типа переводчика